# Js collision detection not showing up proper responses

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple js game, where you can fly your character around the screen. With the help of many Youtube video's and websites I tried coding a collision detection code. If the character touches a bomb, I want an alert box to pop up.
However, it will either give the alert box before I touch the bomb, way after I touch it, or not giving the alert box at all.

I have been attempting to debug this and went through multiple collision detection scripts and stackoverflow collision detection problems but it still wouldn't work.

Does anyone have any tips, suggestions or answers to fix this?
Anything is appreciated! Thank you!

Home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MathMan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Style.css">
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title" class="title">MathMan</h1>
  <hr  id="line" class="line">
  <div class="equations" id="equations">
    <h6 class="paraq">Solve the equation!</h6>
    <hr class="lineq">
    <p class="paraqq">0 + 0 </p>
    <input type="text" class="inputq" id="equationSub">
    <button class="btnq" id="btnQ">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="health" id="healthbar">
    <p class="hearts" id="hearts">
      ♥♥♥
   </p>  
  </div>
  <div class="bombbar" id="bombbar">
    <p class="bombs" id="bombs">
      
   </p>  
  </div>

  <div class="maincontainer" id="maincontainer">
    <div class="instructions" id="instructions">
      <H6 class="parabig">HOW TO PLAY:</H6>
      <p class="para">
        Welcome to MathMan. The objective of this game is  <br>
        to deactivate all the bombs, and save the town !<br>
        To deactivate each bomb, you will be prompted with math<br>
        equations. If you get it wrong, you will lose a life. <br>
        You only have 3 lives, so be careful!<br>
        Press "Start Game" to begin.
      </p>
      <button class="playbtn" id="playBtn">Start Game</button>
    </div>
   
  </div>
   <img class="bomb" id="bomb" src="static/Bomb.png" alt="">
  <img  class= "jotaro" id="idleJotaro" src="static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png">
  <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.js

```
/* Note: I named the character that you control "Jotaro"*/
/* Making it easier by assigning variables  */
const jotaro = document.getElementById("idleJotaro")
const equation = document.getElementById("equations")
const health = document.getElementById("healthbar")
const hearts = document.getElementById("hearts")
const playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn")
const bombbar = document.getElementById("bombbar")
const bombs = document.getElementById("bombs")
const title = document.getElementById("title")
const line = document.getElementById("line")
const bomb = document.getElementById("bomb")
const mainContainer = document.getElementById("maincontainer")

/* Making the in-game elements hidden */
equation.classList.add("hide")
health.classList.add("hide")
bombbar.classList.add("hide")
jotaro.classList.add("hide")
bomb.classList.add("hide")


/* Future stuff for the game, completley unreleated, you can
ignore this*/
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()* (max +1 - min)) + min;
}

function randomOperator(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()* (max +1 - min)) + min;
}

const operators = ["+","-"]

/* start the game event */
playBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame)
/* Keypress event for flying the character*/

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveJotaro)
/* Keypress events for the hovering animation*/

window.addEventListener("keyup", idleJotaro)

/* The variables for storing how much the character 
moved on the Y axis and the X axis when the respective
key gets pressed*/
let jotaroX = 0
let jotaroY = 0


 /* variables for the bombs */
let bombX;
let bombY;
let bombcoliX;
let bombcoliY;
let bombW;
/*spawning the bomb around the screen */
function spawnBomb(){
     bombY = bomb.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
     bombX = bomb.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px";
     bombcoliX = bombX.replace('px','');
     bombcoliY = bombY.replace('px','')
     bombcoliX = Number(bombcoliX)
     bombcoliY = Number(bombcoliY)

    
    while(bombY >= "390px"){
      bombY = bomb.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
    }
    console.log(bombX)
    console.log(bombY)
}

/* when the user starts the game, the in game elements will be
toggled and the instructions will be hidden*/

function startGame(){
     spawnBomb()

    title.classList.add("hide")
    line.classList.add("hide")
    mainContainer.classList.add("hide")

    bombbar.classList.remove("hide")
    health.classList.remove("hide")
    jotaro.classList.remove("hide") 
    bomb.classList.remove("hide")


}

/* When the user releases an arrow key,
 I put in a hovering animation. 
 */
function idleJotaro(event){
    switch(event.key){
        case "ArrowLeft":
            jotaro.classList.add("anim")
            jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            jotaro.classList.add("anim")
            jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
            break;
        case "ArrowUp":
            jotaro.classList.add("anim")
            jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
            break;
         case "ArrowDown":
            jotaro.classList.add("anim")
            jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
            break;
        
    }
}

/* The function that will detect the key that was pressed down,
move the character, and rotate the character in the direction
of the key, and detect if it collided with the bomb. The
 rotating part prob could've been done way easier
, but for now I made it very chunky*/
function moveJotaro(event){
    let jotaroC
    switch(event.key){
        case "ArrowDown":
            jotaroC = jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()
            jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
            /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
            this*/
            if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
                jotaroY += 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            } else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(90deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
                jotaroY += 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else{
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
                jotaroY += 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }
            /* Collision if statment*/
            if(jotaroC.x < bombcoliX + bomb.width &&
                jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombcoliX &&
                jotaroC.y < bombcoliY + bomb.height &&
                jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombcoliY){
                  alert("collideddown")
             }
            break;
        
        case "ArrowUp":
            jotaroC = jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()
            jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
            /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
            this*/
            if(jotaro.style.top == "-30px"){
                jotaroY -= 0;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }
            else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(270deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(360deg)'
                jotaroY -= 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            } else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-270deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-360deg)'
                jotaroY -= 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else{
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
                jotaroY -= 10;
                jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"

            }
            /* Collision if statment*/
            if(jotaroC.x < bombcoliX + bomb.width &&
                jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombcoliX &&
                jotaroC.y < bombcoliY + bomb.height &&
                jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombcoliY){
                  alert("collidedup")
             }
            break;
        
        case "ArrowRight":
            jotaroC = jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()
            jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
           
             
            /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
            this*/
            if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-180deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-270deg)'
                jotaroX += 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            } else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(0deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
                jotaroX += 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else{
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
                jotaroX += 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }
            /* Collision if statment*/
            if(jotaroC.x < bombcoliX + bomb.width &&
                jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombcoliX &&
                jotaroC.y < bombcoliY + bomb.height &&
                jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombcoliY){
                  alert("collidedright")
                  console.log('collidedr')
             }
            break;

         case "ArrowLeft":
            jotaroC = jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()
            jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
            jotaroW = jotaro.style.width
            /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
            this*/
            if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(270deg)') {
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            } else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)'){
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
                
            }else if(jotaro.style.transform === 'rotate(-360deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(0deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-180deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else if(jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-270deg)'){
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
            }else{
                jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-270deg)'
                jotaroX -= 10;
                jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
                jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
                
            }
            /* Collision if statment*/
            if(jotaroC.x < bombcoliX + bomb.width &&
                jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombcoliX &&
                jotaroC.y < bombcoliY + bomb.height &&
                jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombcoliY){
                  alert("collidedleft")
             }
             break;
        
         default: 
             jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
             break;

    }

}
```

Style.css

```
*{
    background-color: rgb(47, 49, 46);
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family:  Calibri, sans-serif;

}




.jotaro {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  
    background-color: none;
    
}
.maincontainer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 270px;
    width: 510px;
    height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;


}

.equations{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    border: 5px solid  rgb(84, 68, 23);
    align-items: center;
    
}

.health{
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    border: 5px solid  rgb(255, 0, 0);
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    align-items: center;

}

.hearts{
    color: red;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 68px;
    height: 0px;
    
}

.bombbar{
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    border: 5px solid  rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    left: 650px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
.bombs {
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 55px;
    height: 0px;
}

.bomb {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.instructions{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    padding: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}
.line{
    border: 0px 0px 5px aliceblue;
}
.lineq{
    border: 5px solid rgb(84, 68, 23);
    margin-top: -70px;
}
.inputq {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    border: 5px solid  rgb(84, 68, 23);
    font-size: large;
    color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
    margin-top: 140px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 100px;

}
.playbtn {
    font-size: larger;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid aliceblue;
    height: 70px;
}
.btnq{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    border: 5px solid  rgb(84, 68, 23);
    font-size: large;
    color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
    margin-top: 140px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
.title{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
}
.para {
  font-size: medium;
}

.parabig{
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: larger;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px aliceblue;
}
.paraq{
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);

    color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.paraqq{
    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.anim {
    animation: hover 1s linear infinite;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
@keyframes hover {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0) 
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your JavaScript code, it will be difficult to pinpoint the exact issue. Here are a couple likely causes of the problem you described:

1. You're using `position: relative`. Unless you're manually adjusting the `jotaroX`, `jotaroY`, `bombcoliX`, and `bombcoliY` values, they will all have an initial value of `0`, causing them to always start in collision. You'll likely have better luck with `position: fixed` for these elements.
2. You're rotating using the CSS `transform` property, which doesn't update the `height` and `width`. The `width` will always be `150px`, even when the image is rotated `90deg`. You can fix this by calling `jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()` and using the `height` and `width` properties of that.

**UPDATE:**

3. You're using *global space* (distance from top left corner of page) for the player, but *local space* (distance from top left corner of parent element) for the bomb. Comparing these two will always give incorrect results unless the parent element of the bomb happens to be at the top left corner of the page.
4. The *hit box* for your collision detection is the image size, which changes based on the direction the player is moving. This might give you unexpected results.

Following are some updates to your code that fix most of these issues. But first, here are a couple tips that will help you debug things like this in the future:

- Try prototyping smaller amounts of code on their own so you can isolate and find bugs quicker. For example, player movement, player animation, collision detection, random placement of bombs, etc. could all be built in their own prototypes with none of the other code getting in the way. When you work the bugs out of each smaller *system*, you'll have an easier time bringing them all together.
- Using `alert` and `console.log` is convenient for debugging, but I'd encourage you to try the browser debugging tools if you haven't already. Adding breakpoints and stepping through the code line by line will reveal wrong assumptions and help you find problems quicker.

Best of luck on your journey!

```js
/* Note: I named the character that you control "Jotaro"*/
/* Making it easier by assigning variables  */
const jotaro = document.getElementById("idleJotaro")
const equation = document.getElementById("equations")
const health = document.getElementById("healthbar")
const hearts = document.getElementById("hearts")
const playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn")
const bombbar = document.getElementById("bombbar")
const bombs = document.getElementById("bombs")
const title = document.getElementById("title")
const line = document.getElementById("line")
const bomb = document.getElementById("bomb")
const mainContainer = document.getElementById("maincontainer")

/* Making the in-game elements hidden */
equation.classList.add("hide")
health.classList.add("hide")
bombbar.classList.add("hide")
jotaro.classList.add("hide")
bomb.classList.add("hide")


/* Future stuff for the game, completley unreleated, you can
ignore this*/
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
}

function randomOperator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
}

const operators = ["+", "-"]

/* start the game event */
playBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame)
/* Keypress event for flying the character*/

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveJotaro)
/* Keypress events for the hovering animation*/

window.addEventListener("keyup", idleJotaro)

/* The variables for storing how much the character 
moved on the Y axis and the X axis when the respective
key gets pressed*/
let jotaroX = 0
let jotaroY = 0


/* variables for the bombs */
let bombC;
/*spawning the bomb around the screen */
function spawnBomb() {
  bomb.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
  bomb.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + "px";


  while (bomb.style.top >= "390px") {
    bomb.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + "px";
  }
  console.log(bomb.style.left)
  console.log(bomb.style.top)
}

/* when the user starts the game, the in game elements will be
toggled and the instructions will be hidden*/

function startGame() {
  spawnBomb()

  title.classList.add("hide")
  line.classList.add("hide")
  mainContainer.classList.add("hide")

  bombbar.classList.remove("hide")
  health.classList.remove("hide")
  jotaro.classList.remove("hide")
  bomb.classList.remove("hide")


}

/* When the user releases an arrow key,
 I put in a hovering animation. 
 */
function idleJotaro(event) {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      jotaro.classList.add("anim")
      jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      jotaro.classList.add("anim")
      jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      jotaro.classList.add("anim")
      jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      jotaro.classList.add("anim")
      jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
      break;

  }
}

/* The function that will detect the key that was pressed down,
move the character, and rotate the character in the direction
of the key, and detect if it collided with the bomb. The
 rotating part prob could've been done way easier
, but for now I made it very chunky*/
function moveJotaro(event) {
  let jotaroC = jotaro.getBoundingClientRect()
  let bombC = bomb.getBoundingClientRect()
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
      jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
      /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
      this*/
      if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
        jotaroY += 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(90deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
        jotaroY += 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-180deg)'
        jotaroY += 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + "px"
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      }
      /* Collision if statment*/
      if (jotaroC.x < bombC.x + bomb.width &&
        jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombC.x &&
        jotaroC.y < bombC.y + bomb.height &&
        jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombC.y) {
        alert(`collideddown (jotaro: ${jotaroC.x} ${jotaroC.y}) (bomb: ${bombC.x} ${bombC.y})`)
      }
      break;

    case "ArrowUp":
      jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
      /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
      this*/
      if (jotaro.style.top == "-30px") {
        jotaroY -= 0;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(270deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(360deg)'
        jotaroY -= 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-270deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-360deg)'
        jotaroY -= 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
        jotaroY -= 10;
        jotaro.style.top = jotaroY + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"

      }
      /* Collision if statment*/
      if (jotaroC.x < bombC.x + bomb.width &&
        jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombC.x &&
        jotaroC.y < bombC.y + bomb.height &&
        jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombC.y) {
        alert(`collidedup (jotaro: ${jotaroC.x} ${jotaroC.y}) (bomb: ${bombC.x} ${bombC.y})`)
      }
      break;

    case "ArrowRight":
      jotaro.classList.remove("anim")


      /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
      this*/
      if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-180deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-270deg)'
        jotaroX += 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(0deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
        jotaroX += 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
        jotaroX += 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      }
      /* Collision if statment*/
      if (jotaroC.x < bombC.x + bomb.width &&
        jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombC.x &&
        jotaroC.y < bombC.y + bomb.height &&
        jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombC.y) {
        alert(`collidedright (jotaro: ${jotaroC.x} ${jotaroC.y}) (bomb: ${bombC.x} ${bombC.y})`)
      }
      break;

    case "ArrowLeft":
      jotaro.classList.remove("anim")
      jotaroW = jotaro.style.width
      /* Rotate and move character to the key, you can ignore
      this*/
      if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(270deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)') {
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"

      } else if (jotaro.style.transform === 'rotate(-360deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(0deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-180deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-90deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else if (jotaro.style.transform == 'rotate(-270deg)') {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"
      } else {
        jotaro.style.transform = 'rotate(-270deg)'
        jotaroX -= 10;
        jotaro.style.left = jotaroX + 'px'
        jotaro.src = "static/flyup.png"

      }
      /* Collision if statment*/
      if (jotaroC.x < bombC.X + bomb.width &&
        jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombC.x &&
        jotaroC.y < bombC.y + bomb.height &&
        jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombC.y) {
        alert(`collidedleft (jotaro: ${jotaroC.x} ${jotaroC.y}) (bomb: ${bombC.x} ${bombC.y})`)
      }
      break;

    default:
      jotaro.src = "static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png"
      break;

  }
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: rgb(47, 49, 46);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.jotaro {
  background-color: tan;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: none;
}

.maincontainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 270px;
  width: 510px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.equations {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  border: 5px solid rgb(84, 68, 23);
  align-items: center;
}

.health {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.hearts {
  color: red;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 68px;
  height: 0px;
}

.bombbar {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  left: 650px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.bombs {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  height: 0px;
}

.bomb {
  background-color: crimson;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.instructions {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid aliceblue;
  padding: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  border: 0px 0px 5px aliceblue;
}

.lineq {
  border: 5px solid rgb(84, 68, 23);
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.inputq {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  border: 5px solid rgb(84, 68, 23);
  font-size: large;
  color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.playbtn {
  font-size: larger;
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid aliceblue;
  height: 70px;
}

.btnq {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  border: 5px solid rgb(84, 68, 23);
  font-size: large;
  color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}

.para {
  font-size: medium;
}

.parabig {
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: larger;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px aliceblue;
}

.paraq {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  color: rgb(84, 68, 23);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.paraqq {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  color: rgb(199, 199, 186);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.anim {
  animation: hover 1s linear infinite;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes hover {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MathMan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title" class="title">MathMan</h1>
  <hr id="line" class="line">
  <div class="equations" id="equations">
    <h6 class="paraq">Solve the equation!</h6>
    <hr class="lineq">
    <p class="paraqq">0 + 0 </p>
    <input type="text" class="inputq" id="equationSub">
    <button class="btnq" id="btnQ">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="health" id="healthbar">
    <p class="hearts" id="hearts">
      ♥♥♥
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bombbar" id="bombbar">
    <p class="bombs" id="bombs">
      
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="maincontainer" id="maincontainer">
    <div class="instructions" id="instructions">
      <H6 class="parabig">HOW TO PLAY:</H6>
      <p class="para">
        Welcome to MathMan. The objective of this game is <br> to deactivate all the bombs, and save the town !<br> To deactivate each bomb, you will be prompted with math<br> equations. If you get it wrong, you will lose a life. <br> You only have 3
        lives, so be careful!<br> Press "Start Game" to begin.
      </p>
      <button class="playbtn" id="playBtn">Start Game</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <img class="bomb" id="bomb" src="static/Bomb.png" alt="">
  <img class="jotaro" id="idleJotaro" src="static/image-removebg-preview__3_-removebg-preview.png">
  <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that `getBoundingClientRect` can be slow. It shouldn't be a problem in your case, as you only call the function on keyboard input. But if it is, you'll just need to swap `height`/`width` manually when `.jotaro` is rotated `90deg`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I used getBoundingClientRect on the jotaro variable (I made it a new variable called jotaroC), but the collision alerts would still come up either too late or too early. For clarification here is the collision code:                                                         if(jotaroC.x < bombcoliX + bomb.width &&
                jotaroC.x + jotaroC.width > bombcoliX &&
                jotaroC.y < bombcoliY + bomb.height &&
                jotaroC.height + jotaroC.y > bombcoliY){
                  alert("collideddown")
             }

Comment: I also added the full js code!

Comment: @Beginnercoder, I updated the answer with more clarification and edits to your code. Thanks for posting the full code. That was super helpful.